# Website only works if all files are world readable

Tags: php, apache, lamp, chmod

Hi I configured LAMP in my local host in UBUNTU, i made all my php files only readable, writable by me. But it only shows a blank page when accessed from a browser i checked my apache error log, and i saw it permission to process the scripts was denied. After changing the the permissions for all the php files to be world readable, the website seems to work fine. Any idea, how I can fix this.

Comment: what user account is `me`, and is that the account your apache is running as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out which user is running the apache ('www', or 'apache', or 'www-data', etc):

Then issue:

```
chown www:www /home/path/to/your/php/files
```

Thus making them belong to apache (not you/root/world)

Comment: I'm seeing is showing that apache is run by www-data, how should i change this? @Kapo && Mark Barker